# please explain this jQuery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is this doing exactly?

```
this.$blah = jQuery("<div id=blahblah1></div>");
```

Answer (score 7):

It's creating a new DOM element (div) wrapped in a jQuery object with the id `blahblah1` and assigning it to a property of the current object.  See the [jQuery Core documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument) for creating elements from HTML.

Comment: and property name starting with a '$' is no different from any other property name, or does it bear some special meaning?

Comment: It doesn't actually assign the div to the $blah property, but a jQuery object referencing that div

Comment: @dalbaeb — No special meaning; '$' is just another name character in JS.  Some folks, however (myself included) like to use it as a Hungarian prefix for jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new jQuery object which contains a newly created `div` with id `blahblah1`.
The jQuery object is then assigned to the $blah property of the current object.